# linkedin oauth2 login returns "504 Gateway Time-out"

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, http-status-code-504, request-timed-out

I'm using linkedin login on my website. Everything was working until last week, when it started returning "504 Gateway Time-out" error. I did not change anything in my application settings on linkedin developer site nor in my application code. Weird thing is that it still works fine on localhost, but on production it returns error described above. My question is:

Is it more likely to be a problem on Linkedin side? Because for me it seems that my website is trying to connect to linkedin API but it never gets a response.

Unfortunately I have not found any address that I could contact regarding this problem. Is there any linkedin support for this ? Or have any of you were experiencing similar problem?

Thank you

Comment: Should be noted, that LinkedIn returns `200` code after OAuth2 authentication. It returns tokens and everything, but `504` fires afterwards. So, a PHP script is waiting for some response and does time out afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue the solution was to set the header *Content-Type* to *application/json*.

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedIn Developer API appears to be down. Requests to:

```
api.linkedin.com/v1/people/
```

are failing consistently.

And while this might be a separate issue, it's worth noting that the documentation for integrating with their OAuth2 service is no longer accessible at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2.

Comment: I am seeing similar issues. Everything was fine up until ~7pm ET for us. Now our apps that use LinkedIn auth (via python-linkedin v4.1) are failing with errors like HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.linkedin.com', port=443): Read timed out. I've raised a support request with LinkedIn too.

Comment: If you are using linkedin API 1.0 then try to move in 2.0 before 1st march. Please read this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context